# How to create a product group using google ad words API in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client

I need to create a new product group. I have used below library to do that process.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib.

I tried  add Shopping campaign to create a new product group.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201806/ShoppingCampaigns/AddShoppingCampaign.php

I don't know whether it is correct or wrong. If the method is correct,

```
const BUDGET_ID = 'INSERT_BUDGET_ID_HERE';
const MERCHANT_ID = 'INSERT_MERCHANT_ID_HERE';
```

I want to know where can i get "BUDGET Id". Otherwise please provide the sample code to create product group using google ad words API.

Note: *I am new to google ad words.*

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.